# crontab doesn't run the links2 command

Tags: linux

I'm trying run the following command every 1 minute using crontab, but the command doesn't run.

```
1 * * * *  /usr/bin/links2 http://localhost/tomada/temperatura/servidor.php
```

The command works fine using the shell

What is the problem?

Comment: Is there any information in /var/log/syslog (or /var/log/dmesg or /var/log/message depending on your distribution) regarding the cron job?  Also links2 appears to be a gui browser depending on what user is running the cron job they may or may not have access to your x screen.  What is the desired result from the cron job?

Comment: That will run every hour at one minute past the hour, not every minute. I think you mean `*/1 * * * *`

Comment: HI, I found links in file syslog and receive it: May 21 20:25:01 raspberrypi links2: checking tty name failed

Comment: the links2 can't start, I tried use sudo before but receive the same error

Comment: Means what it says -- it needs a TTY.  Why are you using `links2` anyhow, and not curl, or wget, or something meant for noninteractive use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First -- don't use `links` for that purpose; it's built to be an interactive browser, but a cron job by its nature is noninteractive. `curl` is the right tool for the job:

```
* * * * *  curl http://localhost/tomada/temperatura/servidor.php
```

...or, if you can't use curl (why?), then wget:

```
* * * * *  wget -O - http://localhost/tomada/temperatura/servidor.php
```

Second -- if you **must** use links, use it in an explicitly noninteractive way, such as with `-dump` or `-source`:

```
* * * * *  /usr/bin/links2 -dump http://localhost/tomada/temperatura/servidor.php
```

Comment: You already have the answer. Please add the every minute as well. It's in the OP's question.

Comment: Don't need `*/1`, that can just be a leading `*`, then.